# Injecting Configuration object to a service bean during Unit test in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, configuration

**Problem Summary:**

A configuration object is created successfully during regular run (using `@Autowired`), but is `null` when running in unit test phase.

**Edit, in response to flagging the question as duplicate:** 
I don't think this is a duplication of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) as my question is about unit test phase and the above question is about regular run phase.

**Detailed:**

I have a configuration object that reads a properties file:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "defaults")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DefaultsConfigProperties {
   Double value;
   ....
```

In the service layer, I'm using this class successfully when running the app in regular mode:

```
@Service
@Configuration   
public class CatsService {

@Autowired
DefaultsConfigProperties defaultsConfigProperties;
...
```

However, **the problem is during Unit test**, as the `defaultsConfigProperties` is `null`.

Here is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "defaults.value=0.2"
})
public class CatServiceTest {
private CatService;

@Before
public void before(){
    catService = new CatService();
}
```

If I understand correctly, I need to somehow create / inject / mock the `DefaultsConfigProperties` class during the unit test phase.

I also know that using the `@Autowired` is not recommended and it is better to pass items to the constructor of the class.
So, should the solution be that the `CatService` will need to accept the `DefaultsConfigProperties` in the constructor, and then to create it (how?) in the `CatServiceTest` ?

Comment: You're doing 2 separate things here that lead to an entirely different test scenario. **(1)** Either you're using Spring to create a `DefaultsConfigProperties` with value `0.2` within your test. In this case, the duplicate is still valid because you're self-creating `CatService`. **(2)** Alternatively you're trying to create a dummy `DefaultsConfigProperties` class, but in that case you don't need `@SpringBootTest`, `@TestPropertySource`, ... . Since the duplicate still applies in situation (1), I'm not going to vote to reopen unless you clarify that within your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, as you stated constructor injection is favored above field injection.

Nevertheless if you want to rely on field injection you could use `Mockito`.

Example for usage in a unit test:

```
@Mock
DefaultsConfigProperties defaultsConfigProperties;

@InjectMocks
private CatService;

@Before
public void before(){
    catService = new CatService();
    MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}
```

So in your case you should also remove the annotations of your test class to make it a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation takes a `classes` array parameter. You can pass any class annotated with `@Configuration` into this array, and also the class containing your main method (`SpringApplication.run(...)`) if you want to load the same `ApplicationContext`. In your case:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, DefaultsConfigProperties.class})
```

Note you can also use `SpringRunner` directly.